# difference between char (*test)[] vs char *test1[] and how elegantly initialize test?

Tags: c++

just excersize from stroustrup: declare and initialize pointer of string array.
I can do

```
char *test1[]={"ddd"}
```

but can't

```
char (*test)[] ={"dfsdf"}.
```

which is difference between these declarations and how initialize second ?

Comment: If you read [this page](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html), it might help you decipher the declarations yourself.

Answer (score 1):

First is an array of pointers to the type `char`.
Second is a pointer to array of type `char`.

This small **[code snippet](http://ideone.com/X9WLol)** should be good to understand the difference:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
   char *test1[]={"ddd","aaa"};
   printf("[%s]",test1[0]);   
   printf("[%s]",test1[1]);   

   char arr[]={"bbb"};
   char (*test2)[] = &arr;
   printf("[%s]",*test2);

   return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
[ddd][aaa][bbb]
```

`test1` is a array of pointers, each subscript of this array points to character string.
`test1[0]` & `test1[1]` allow you to obtain the content being pointed.

`test2` is pointer to another array. Dereferencing the pointer `*test2` gives you the array being pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

You have created an **array of pointers** with the following code:

```
char *test1[]={"ddd"};
```

The code below is a pointer to an array.  `"ddd"` is implicitly an array of characters.

```
char *test1 = "ddd";
```

Comment: "This is a pointer to an array." - If you mean that `char *test[]` is a pointer to an array, then it isn't. `char (*test)[]` is a pointer to array.

Comment: @H2CO3 I must have worded it poorly.  I've added "the code below".